# How to backup using backup API's in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, backup, volume-shadow-service

I am writing an application that used to backup some specified file, therefore using the backup API calls i.e **CreateFile BackupRead and WriteFile API's**.

getting errors Access violation reading location.

I have attached code below.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hInput, hOutput;

//m_filename is a variable holding the file path to read from
hInput = CreateFile(L"C:\\Key.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

//strLocation contains the path of the file I want to create.
hOutput= CreateFile(L"C:\\tmp\\", GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL); 


DWORD dwBytesToRead = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
BYTE *buffer;
buffer = new BYTE[dwBytesToRead];
BOOL bReadSuccess = false,bWriteSuccess = false;
DWORD dwBytesRead,dwBytesWritten;
LPVOID lpContext;
//Now comes the important bit:

do
{
    bReadSuccess = BackupRead(hInput, buffer, sizeof(BYTE) *dwBytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, false, true, &lpContext);

    bWriteSuccess= WriteFile(hOutput, buffer, sizeof(BYTE) *dwBytesRead, &dwBytesWritten, NULL); 

}while(dwBytesRead == dwBytesToRead);

return 0;
```

}

Any one suggest me how to use these API's?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't thin windows from Vista to windows 8 will allow you create files in C: directory in program

Comment: it jus an example, destination location may be anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation.  Specifically, the second paragraph of the documentation for [`BackupRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362509.aspx):

> You must set the variable pointed to by `lpContext` to `NULL` before the first call to `BackupRead` for the specified file or directory.

Your code is also in dire need of error handling--you do no checking for errors at all, when in fact many of these APIs may fail (check the documentation for each API to learn how the function may fail and what happens when it fails).  You should also implement correct resource handling, e.g. by closing the file handles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply James.
After setting lpContext to NULL, I am not getting access voilation error
But this appln is not backing up the file.
'll work on it by hanling error for each API.